# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'oscpack.lib'

Tags: visual-c++, point-cloud-library

I am trying to run code for skeleton tracking using the Point Cloud Library. While building project the in MSVC 10, I get this error

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'oscpack.lib'

What might cause this and how do I solve it?

Comment: Did you check your library paths?

Comment: yes i did, but there is no such library.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is not the linker error, but the absence of the library altogether? Then make sure to get all the dependencies of your project. I guess this one is missing: https://code.google.com/p/oscpack/